# How to multiply a table with a column of another table in postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql

I would like to multiply some columns (all except the geom, gid, foreign key) of a table `A` with a column of another table `B.sum` with the condition :
 `WHERE A.gid = B.gid`

I was thinking to do something like this pseudo code:

```
FOR r IN SELECT [list of the column to multiply] 
DO 
A.r* B.sum
WHERE A.gid = B.gid
```

How can I implement this in postgresql?

Should I use `PL/pgSQL` or `PL/Python`?

or using `geopandas` ?

Comment: Do you want to get a separated value for each multiplication or just grouped?

Comment: I need to have a table like A with each cell multiplied by B.sum. I need gid to respect tables' connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply chosen columns by a coefficient in a simple query, e.g.:

```
with table_a(gid, col1, col2) as (
values
    (1, 10, 20),
    (2, 10, 30)
),
table_b(gid, sum) as (
values
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3)
)

select gid, col1* sum as col1, col2* sum as col2
from table_a
join table_b using(gid)

 gid | col1 | col2 
-----+------+------
   1 |   20 |   40
   2 |   30 |   90
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you!  

In the end I used this on a loop with `psycopg2`: 



`UPDATE table_a SET col1 = col1 * sum
                        FROM table_b  WHERE table_a.foren_gid = table_b.gid;`